# Failed to reload-or-try-restart bulk services

Tags: kubuntu

As you can see by running the below command, a lot of services were not found even some essentials eg. pulseaudio (i have problems with my audio).

So what is happening? if they are old services, how i can remove them from where?

(this is after a machine restart)
[see here journal file](https://ufile.io/q2t6jpq4)

```
sudo systemctl force-reload *
[sudo] password for elias: 
Invalid unit name "Calibre Library" escaped as "Calibre\x20Library" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).
Invalid unit name "GOG Games" escaped as "GOG\x20Games" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).
Invalid unit name "peaker-test -Dsysdefault -c2" escaped as "peaker-test\x20-Dsysdefault\x20-c2" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).
Invalid unit name "VirtualBox VMs" escaped as "VirtualBox\x20VMs" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).
Failed to reload-or-try-restart 1.4.9.1088-linux-x64.zip.service: Unit 1.4.9.1088-linux-x64.zip.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart 1.4.9.1088-linux-x64.zip.1.service: Unit 1.4.9.1088-linux-x64.zip.1.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Audio.service: Unit Audio.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart backup.ab.service: Unit backup.ab.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart _build.service: Unit _build.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Calibre\x20Library.service: Unit Calibre\x20Library.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart chkrootkit-0.52.service: Unit chkrootkit-0.52.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Data.service: Unit Data.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Desktop.service: Unit Desktop.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Documents.service: Unit Documents.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart do-release-upgrade.service: Unit do-release-upgrade.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Downloads.service: Unit Downloads.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart fix-ubuntu-bluetooth-adapter.service: Unit fix-ubuntu-bluetooth-adapter.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg.service: Unit githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart gnulib.service: Unit gnulib.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart GOG\x20Games.service: Unit GOG\x20Games.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart gtk-recordMyDesktop-crash.log.service: Unit gtk-recordMyDesktop-crash.log.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart history.service: Unit history.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart libreoffice.service: Unit libreoffice.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart LICENSE.txt.service: Unit LICENSE.txt.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Lightworks.service: Unit Lightworks.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart local.service: Unit local.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Mango.service: Unit Mango.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart manifest.json.service: Unit manifest.json.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Mindwave.service: Unit Mindwave.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart my-websit.service: Unit my-websit.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart output.csv.service: Unit output.csv.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart peaker-test\x20-Dsysdefault\x20-c2.service: Unit peaker-test\x20-Dsysdefault\x20-c2.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Pictures.service: Unit Pictures.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart prefix32.service: Unit prefix32.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart pspp.jnl.service: Unit pspp.jnl.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Public.service: Unit Public.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart qt_temp.service: Unit qt_temp.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart qt_temp2.service: Unit qt_temp2.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart R.service: Unit R.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Release.key.service: Unit Release.key.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Release.key.1.service: Unit Release.key.1.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart REPOS_PATH.service: Unit REPOS_PATH.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart set.service: Unit set.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart signal-desktop-keyring.gpg.service: Unit signal-desktop-keyring.gpg.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart snap.service: Unit snap.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart src.service: Unit src.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart themes.service: Unit themes.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Ubu1.avi.service: Unit Ubu1.avi.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart ui.service: Unit ui.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart Videos.service: Unit Videos.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart VirtualBox\x20VMs.service: Unit VirtualBox\x20VMs.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart vokoscreenNG.service: Unit vokoscreenNG.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart winedotnet.service: Unit winedotnet.service not found.
Failed to reload-or-try-restart winehq.key.service: Unit winehq.key.service not found.
```